# Catch event in sibling component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

My app looks like this :

```
<my-app>
  <my-toolbar></my-toolbar>
  <my-cube-container></my-cube-container >
</my-app>
```

I'd like to communicate from `my-toolbar` to `my-cube-container`.
I'm sending an event from the toolbar :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-toolbar',
  template: `...
                    <i class="fa fa-search-minus ic" (click)='onZoom(-1)' aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    `,
})
export class ToolbarComponent {
@Output() zoomEvent: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  onZoom(value:number){
    console.log('event sent');
    this.zoomEvent.emit(value);
  }
}
```

And first I wanted to catch the event in the sibling which is `my-cube-container` (see app structure above). However I read that this relation of emitting event and catching those are solely reserved for parent children communication. ** Is that the case ? **

So I tried to communicate with the parent instead then (and create another eventEmitter in the future so I can catch the event in my target component `my-cube-container`). However I'm still not catching the event.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
              <my-toolbar></my-toolbar>
              <my-cube-container (zoomEvent)="onZoom($event)"></my-cube-container>

            `
})
export class AppComponent {
  onZoom(val){
    console.log("event catched");
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong ? Do I need to change something in ngModul ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use template variables to reference siblings from within the template

```
<my-toolbar (zoomEvent)="container.onZoom($event)"></my-toolbar>
<my-cube-container #container></my-cube-container >
```

Comment: The parenthesis around (zoomEvent) are supposed to mean that it's my-toolbar that is catching it's own event. It seems a bit backward -or redundant is a better word- since it is the component emitting the event in the first place. Isn't there a built-in way to directly do that from within the Component class ?

Comment: It's not `my-toolbar` that is catching the event. It's actually the component that has this HTML in the template (the common parent). You can use a shared service and observables to communicate between components that are not direct parent-child, but that seems overkill for such a simple case.