# What are the difference between the technics to pass data from components to others in Angular2?

Tags: angular, components

I am wondering why there is different technics to share data between components in Angular2 as explain here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

For example, "input binding" is very easy to use. Why would I bother to "Parent and children communicate via a service"?

Is there performance issues? Or they are quite the same and it only depends on how it is easier to maintain.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input binding is used for direct family (parent - child) while you can use services for other relationships. I believe this is a design choice.

Like here, they both can communicate because they are "touching" each other (wow that went weird really fast):

```
<parent>
  <child/>
</parent>
```

Here you can use Input, Output, it's fast and elegant.

Where as

```
<parent>
 <child>
  <subchild></subchild>
 </child>
 <otherChild>
   <otherSubChild></otherSubChild>
 </otherChild>
</parent>
```

Here if you would like to communicate from otherSubChild to subChild you'd use a service because they are not closely related.

Altough, for brothers communication there is a neat trick : [Catch event in sibling component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047451/catch-event-in-sibling-component/39047499?noredirect=1#comment65445139_39047499)

```
<parent (event)="sis.onEvent">
  <bro/> <-- this is the guy emitting the event
  <sis #sis/>
</parent>
```

So in other words, as long as they are "touching" (god, I need a better word), each other you don't have to rely on a service.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it should be used a service to make "brother" communicate? <parent> <child/><child/><parent/> ?

Comment: @JohnDoetheDoe I edited my response, is that what you mean by brother communcation ? I actually asked kind of the same question a couple days ago :)